# Search document from document library on basis of current login user

Tags: document-library, search

i want to implement search on a document library.if current login user is from "creator" group he will see only those document in search which was created by him /her only. if from other group will see all document in serach result. How this search can be implemented.?

Comment: How are you implementing the "creator group"? Security or User Profiles?

Comment: i have 4,5 groups "Creator, approver" etc .some documents saved in document library. now i want when i search document in SharePoint 2013 and logged in user is from creator group he will see only those documents which is created by him only.

Comment: Maybe you can create security trimmed result. Checkout this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/security_trimming_in_sharepoint_2013/

Comment: I have never tried creating a search query that includes group permissions. Not sure if it's possible.